# Force Chrome cursor update when mouse-idling vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, chromium

I have a similar issue as related in this link :

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=26723

When new div appears and when mouse does not move, cursor is not updated in Chrome 40.
The Chrome issue list some workarounds, but I don't get them to work with my code.
There are also some stackoverflow question listing this issue but they don't fix this particular case with vanilla javascript.

HTML :

```
<div id ="d">
    Hello
</div>
```

CSS :

```
div#d {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}

div.curs {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: grey;
}
```

JS :

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var div = document.getElementById('d');
    div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + '<div class="curs">World</div>';    
}, 5000);
```

What is the easiest vanilla javascript workaround for this particular case?

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2zh90st6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Google Chrome v42, you can schedule a cursor update by changing the cursor style of the element currently under the cursor, or any of this element's ancestors. Note that the cursor style has to change **after** the new element has been added to the DOM.

```js
var container, overlay;

container = document.getElementById('container');

setTimeout(function() {
  overlay = document.createElement('div');
  overlay.id = 'overlay';
  container.appendChild(overlay);

  // Change container cursor from 'auto' to 'default',
  // to schedule cursor update while hovering overlay
  container.style.cursor = 'default';
}, 5000);
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: auto;
  background: #7FDBFF;
  color: #001F3F;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
#overlay {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #001F3F;
  color: #7FDBFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  Hover me and wait for a dark overlay.
</div>
```

The chromium issue you linked to, [Issue 26723: Mouse cursor doesn't change when mouse-idling](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=26723), seems quite active at the moment, so hopefully this kind of workaround won't be required for long.

Comment: Still get this problem on Chrome 67. Beware the cursor doesn't update if the page doesn't have keyboard focus (e.g. press F12 and cursor *doesn't* change). Secondly the cursor wouldn't change if a div moves underneath a stationary mouse pointer. Dirty fix: http://jsbin.com/qahuqa/1 - open and put the mouse pointer near the top left: the CSS cursor is updated when the green box goes underneath the mouse pointer. Now press F12 and the cursor is *not* updated (because devtools has focus). From devtools Elements tab, right click, delete <div id="dummyCursorDiv"></div> and cursor doesn't update.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm this is interesting. Either way, triggering a change in the body's cursor, seems to do the trick in Chrome v42:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var div = document.getElementById('d');
    div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + '<div class="curs">World</div>';    

    document.body.style.cursor = 'default';

}, 5000);
```