# CSS/JavaScript - Force hover state update in Safari

Tags: javascript, css, safari, webkit

When uploading a file in Safari the `:hover` state freezes until the mouse is moved again, see this example:

```css
input:hover{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
How to reproduce: open this is Safari, click on the input, choose a file and don't move the mouse. The hove state does not update!<br><br>

<input type="file">
```

Is there any way I can force a repaint/update of the cursor position? I have tried the following solutions, which do not work in this case:

- [How can I force WebKit to redraw/repaint to propagate style changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485365/how-can-i-force-webkit-to-redraw-repaint-to-propagate-style-changes)
- [Force Chrome cursor update when mouse-idling vanilla javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190802/force-chrome-cursor-update-when-mouse-idling-vanilla-javascript)

Does anyone have a different Javascript or CSS solution, that tells the browser to update the cursor position after the change event is fired? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think I'm not understanding properly. In Edge/Chrome for example if I hover on the input I get the red, as expected. Then if I don't move the mouse but select the file with the enter key I still have the red. Isn't this what you expect? It's still hovered. Can you explain a bit more what is the problem?

Comment: @AHaworth In Safari there seems to be a bug. You don’t have to use the enter key to select, just click on it, choose a file and don’t move to mouse afterwards. The background remains red (even if the mouse is no longer hovering!) until the mouse is moved again. I am looking for a way to repaint the screen to circumvent this bug.